# OCR library for Blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, ocr

Does anybody now some tool that can help me to recognize numeric values from photos in Java-based Blackberry application?

Comment: hello Alex, I am developing a blackberry OCR application. Please suggest me if you are done with your stuff. I am struggling from last 3 days, I hope you can guide me with some useful stuff and suggestions.:(

Answer (score 0):

[Aspire](http://asprise.com/product/ocr/index.php?lang=java) is a java based OCR SDK. I am not sure how much it will useful for Blackberry. Try yourself.

Another one is [JavaOCR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/). It is 100% java. Its author posts on his [blog.](http://www.roncemer.com/software-development/java-ocr)